# Wordpress temp folder under WP-Content

Tags: wordpress

At work we have something strange going on with our WordPress Website.
It creates temp folder with few files under WP-content folder.
One of the file is automatically getting bigger on size for no reason around 1GB a day( I keep deleting it)
I can't find what is creating this files.
Folder is like this temp_750d5f958f2e5b3db45305632919a5ed

I am not sure if this is word-press or plugin but it wont stop until it reach the server capacity.

Thanks for any advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have no idea about which plugin or theme or injection does it:

1. Install this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/string-locator/
2. Search for string 'temp_' inside your filesystem.

You will find more than 10 results. The file which contains a string similar to `"temp_<?php echo md5(...."` is the one you are looking for.

or if you want to it in local PC:

1. Download your WP installation home directory to your local PC.
2. Install any Code Searcher software to your PC. (for Linux, Searchmonkey is recommended. For Mac and Windows you can try DocFetcher)
3. Search for string 'temp_' inside your filesystem.

Comment: Thank you very much , all sorted now :)